# How to make proper Cavity and Curvature map?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

Does anyone know how to make proper `Cavity` and `Curvature` maps that can be used in texture painting or game engines?

Comment: You could use Ambient Occlusion

Comment: Can you define those terms? What is a cavity map? An information if an edge's faces' normals point towards or away from each-other? How about the curvature map, is it the same thing? If not, it would warrant a separate question.

Comment: A cavity map isn't really "proper"-- it depends on the parameters that the artist sent it, and it's intended for a purpose, and so tuned to eye.  A cavity map is simply an AO map with a lower-than-normal distance.  (Use an AO node, tune distance to eye, bake.)  Curvature maps are not used in game engines, because they depend on deformation; you'd instead use delta(normal), which gives you the difference between normals of adjacent samples.  "Delta" depends on shader engine, but IIRC, in HLSL, it's "ddx()" or "ddy()".  If Blender, no delta, so do it in compositing.